# Which value fits the best for Parameter SIZEUNITS for Googles Web Mercator Projection EPSG 3857 to show a radius in meters

Tags: postgis, style, mapserver, mapfile

[image]In my mapfile there is a WMS definition, which shows a circle buffer and it's radius in meters. I offer UTM-Systems and Googles Pseudo Mercator. In UTM and `SIZEUNIT meters` it works fine. Please, could someone give an advice which fits the best for Pseudo Mercator Projection?

```
SYMBOLSCALEDENOM 24000
SIZEUNITS meters

CLASS
    NAME 'Test'

    STYLE               
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        PATTERN 40 10 END
        WIDTH 1
    END

    STYLE
        GEOMTRANSFORM "centroid"
            COLOR 0 0 0
            SYMBOL "vertline"
            SIZE [radius]
            WIDTH 3
            ANGLE 60
        END         
    END
END
```

I've tried an Approximation in my POSTGIS SQL-Request:
`radius / (2*PI()/10) AS r_google` 
this would be enough for me.

How can I tell MAPSERVER which radius to use, when the projection system changes? Is there a Switch-Statement for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution is a workaround with POSTGIS.

```
LAYER
    NAME        Radius
    TYPE        LINE
    STATUS      ON
    METADATA
...
    END

    CONNECTIONTYPE PostGIS
    CONNECTION ...

    DATA "geom FROM (SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_Centroid(geom), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1)) FROM myview) AS foo USING UNIQUE id USING srid=4326"

    SYMBOLSCALEDENOM 24000
    SIZEUNITS meters

    CLASS
        NAME 'Radius'
        MAXSCALEDENOM 24000               

        STYLE               
            OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
            PATTERN 40 10 END
            WIDTH 1
        END                     
    END
END
```